# Como fazer deploy de um container Windows no Heroku?

Tags: asp.net, docker, heroku, microsoft

Estou tentando fazer o `deploy`de um `container` `Windows` no [`Heroku`](http://heroku.com/) porém estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform
> ```

No site do `Heroku` tenho a seguinte informação:

> **Develop with Docker, deploy to Heroku**
>
> Use Docker for local development on Windows, Linux, or Mac. When you're ready, just push your code and Dockerfile to build and deploy your Docker images to Heroku.

O que me leva a pensar que é possível realizar o `deploy` utilizando uma imagem `Windows`.

Meu `Dockerfile` é o seguinte:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

E meu `heroku.yml` é o seguinte:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: swagger-aspnet-docker/Dockerfile
run:
  web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

O Heroku e a maioria dos servidores só fazem deploy de imagens com base no kernel linux por causa de limitações do Windows, quando ele diz em rodar no Windows e subir para o Heroku ele esta dizendo para você desenvolver em uma imagem base linux localmente e subir aplicação, o docker aproveita o kernel do SO, imagens de base Windows não conseguem utilizar o kernel do linux por isso não tem suporte, nesse caso você teria que contratar um servidor windows e instalar o docker para fazer o deploy nesta maquina

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer pra subir esse servidor? Não tem como usar uma outra imagem que não seja `Windows`?

Comment: 1- Você pode contratar o serviço docker entreprase https://www.docker.com/products/windows-containers

Comment: 2 - Existem soluções da AWS https://aws.amazon.com/pt/windows/

Comment: 3 - Pode usar a própria plataforma da microsoft https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/kubernetes-service/docker/

Comment: existem diversas outras abordagens mas acredito que essas os similares serão as melhores pra você

Comment: @Sorack Pela imagem, nota-se que estamos falando de uma aplicação ASP .NET 4.7, baseada em .NET Framework. O .NET Framework não suporta deployment no linux. Teria de portar pra Mono para poder validar.

Comment: isso que eu tentei explicar